# Handling errors with React and Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to get errors directly inside **Formik** and log the errors on the console but t it's not working.

1. **Submit function**

```
const submitForms = (errors) => {
    console.log("ERRORS ON SUBMIT", errors);
    handleNext();
  };
```

2. **Attempt to catch errors inside Formik**

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{ ...initialValues }}
  validationSchema={kycFormSchema}
  onSubmit={({errors}) => submitForms(errors)}
 />
```

I'm actually using Yup to validate the form but I also want to catch the errors and pass them in **submitForms** function. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like according to the official documentation **onSubmit()** function of the Formik library doesn't de-structure any error props.

You can find the list of available props within **onSubmit()** at the following link : [FORMIK | onSubmit( )](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany)

This is the functidefinition of the onSubmit() function :

- **onSubmit: (values: Values, formikBag: FormikBag) => void |
  Promise**

Answer (score 0):

If the form doesn't pass `validationSchema`, `onSubmit` will not call. It only call when don't have errors. `onSubmit` only have params are values and  [FormikBag](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany).

> Note: errors, touched, status and all event handlers are NOT included in the FormikBag.

You can use `errors` is a props of a Child Component: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#component-reactcomponenttypeformikpropsvalues

```
<Formik component={ContactForm} />;
 
 const ContactForm = ({
   handleSubmit,
   handleChange,
   handleBlur,
   values,
   errors,
 }) => (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <input
       type="text"
       onChange={handleChange}
       onBlur={handleBlur}
       value={values.name}
       name="name"
     />
     {errors.name && <div>{errors.name}</div>}
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
 );
```